# jqGrid - modal window before do operation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I use jqGrid, I have button, and when click i do archive operation. I need when i click button, to open modal window with text **Do you real wants to add row to archive?** and 2 button **Yes** & **No** if i click **Yes** operation must do it and modal is closed, and if i click **No** operation is will canceled and modal windows is closed.
I think you understand what i need.

```
$gridI.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", pager,
    {
        caption: "Add to Archive",
        title: "Add to Archive",
        icon: "ui-icon-flag",
        onClickButton: function () {
            if (!$gridI.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow')) {
                alert('Please chose row');
                return true;
            }
            $(this).jqGrid("extRequest",
                    {
                        "oper": "archive" //oper name
                    },
                    {
                        'selrow': true   //add selected rows to request
                    });
        }
    });
```

P.S. Sorry for bad english. Thx.

Comment: I think it is very easy question )) Maybe anybody help.
Thx. Very match :*

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple Javascript "confirm" - so you dont need an extra plugin for that.

Try something like that:

```
var check = confirm("Do you real wants to add row to archive?");
if (check == true) {

    // Ok pressed

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either what derdida said, or a modal.

jqModal seems like a good choice to go along with your jqGrid :)

http://jquery.iceburg.net/jqModal/